# Join instead of correlated subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE BlogPosts 
(
PostID INT PRIMARY KEY  not null,
PostTitle NVARCHAR ,
BlogID int,
TotalComments int
)
```

May this query be simplified with any Join instead of correlated subquery?

```
SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM BlogPosts as t0
WHERE t0.PostID = (SELECT TOP 1 t1.PostID 
                FROM BlogPosts as t1
                WHERE t0.BlogID = t1.BlogID
                ORDER BY t1.TotalComments DESC)
```

I need 5 posts with max TotalComments from different blogs.

UPD. SQL Server, but I would prefer standard SQL

Comment: Your stated sql is not ordered, so the top 5 in it is not guaranteed to return any specific five rows... There may be more thabn 5 rows that satisfy the Where clause... As you've written it, you might get all five from the same blog, or a mixture. Which of them do you want?

Comment: No, i need top commented posts from different blogs always, not from the same blogs, otherwise it would be easier:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly, postid is unique, so this should help

EDIT:

OK try this then

```
DECLARE @BlogPosts  TABLE
( 
    PostID INT PRIMARY KEY  not null, 
    PostTitle NVARCHAR , 
    BlogID int, 
    TotalComments int 
) 

INSERT INTO @BlogPosts (PostID,PostTitle,BlogID,TotalComments) SELECT 1, 'A', 1, 3
INSERT INTO @BlogPosts (PostID,PostTitle,BlogID,TotalComments) SELECT 2, 'B', 1, 4
INSERT INTO @BlogPosts (PostID,PostTitle,BlogID,TotalComments) SELECT 3, 'C', 2, 5
INSERT INTO @BlogPosts (PostID,PostTitle,BlogID,TotalComments) SELECT 4, 'D', 2, 6
INSERT INTO @BlogPosts (PostID,PostTitle,BlogID,TotalComments) SELECT 5, 'E', 2, 7
INSERT INTO @BlogPosts (PostID,PostTitle,BlogID,TotalComments) SELECT 6, 'F', 1, 8
INSERT INTO @BlogPosts (PostID,PostTitle,BlogID,TotalComments) SELECT 7, 'G', 3, 9
INSERT INTO @BlogPosts (PostID,PostTitle,BlogID,TotalComments) SELECT 8, 'H', 4, 10
INSERT INTO @BlogPosts (PostID,PostTitle,BlogID,TotalComments) SELECT 9, 'I', 5, 11
INSERT INTO @BlogPosts (PostID,PostTitle,BlogID,TotalComments) SELECT 10, 'J', 6, 5

SELECT  TOP 5 *
FROM    @BlogPosts bp INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  BlogID,
                    MAX(TotalComments) MaxComments
            FROM    @BlogPosts
            GROUP BY BlogID
        ) maxCommentsPerBlog ON bp.BlogID = maxCommentsPerBlog.BlogID
                            AND bp.TotalComments = maxCommentsPerBlog.MaxComments
ORDER BY bp.TotalComments DESC
```

You might have multiple max blog-totalComments combinations though.

Comment: @astander: Why "@BlogPosts" instead of "BlogPosts"? It's not a temporary table.

Comment: This was my test table in TSQL

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the top post per blog:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, Ranking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BlogID ORDER BY TotalComments DESC)
  FROM BlogPosts
  ) a
WHERE Ranking = 1
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT BlogID 
  FROM BlogPosts 
  ) a
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 b.* FROM BlogPosts b
  WHERE a.BlogID = b.BlogID
  ORDER BY b.TotalComments DESC
  ) b
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: With Partition it is nice, thank you, may be even nicer than with join.

Answer (score 0):

why you need joins and subqueries?
Why you cant write

```
SELECT  TOP 5 *
FROM    @BlogPosts bp order by TotalComments desc;
```

Comment: Probably because @rudnev needs top 5 "from different blogs". Your query could return e.g. top 5 from only one blog.